# SyntaxError in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pycharm, python-2.x

Can someone help me fix this issue:

[image: SyntaxError in PyCharm]

```
File "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/NoteBot/main.py", line 5
    PATH =
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That error message doesn't match the posted code (which should be posted as text, not as a screenshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to run the PS5 bot using the inbuilt python that comes on your mac, i.e., probably Python2.7.

The issue is the author of the bot used a feature introduced in Python 3.5 called [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

So you need to change the version of Python that Pycharm is using to a version above 3.5 (google this). Or just run the script from the Terminal app using:

```
python3 /Users/mac/PycharmProjects/NoteBot/main.py
```

Note: You may need to install selenium etc. again here using `pip3`. Pycharm probably will handle this for you if you get it to point at a Python3 installation.

Furthermore, if you want to learn to program in Python yourself after you snag a PS5 you may want to look into [**pyenv**](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).